# SQLYog: Copy partial data?

Tags: mysql, copy, sqlyog

For testing code I'm copying data from a live database to a test database using SQLYog's "Copy to different host" option.  Most of the time, this is okay.  But for some tables the dataset is absolutely huge and I only need a relatively small subset of the data for testing.  The Copy to different host dialog gives you the option of copying structure only or structure and data.

If I only want partial data, I have to run a `select * on table where condition` query, export the results as an SQL query, import that query into the test host and run it.  While this works, it's not exactly a fun procedure, especially given circumstances where even the "small" subset of test data is still a lot of rows.  If some of the data was already copied over than that adds further complications, as I have to write a query to get a list of keys on the target and then add a `where key not in (key list)` condition onto the main condition.

Is there a way to get the "copy to different host" feature to only selectively copy rows to the target database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to use a WHERE condition on individual rows in the [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com) copy tool.  As long as only a single table is selected for copy it is OK, but with more tables it won't make sense.

What you can do now is to create a small 'dummy' table on source and copy this one. The workflow could be like:

1) CREATE TABLE `newtable` AS SELECT * FROM `oldtable` WHERE ...

2) Now copy `newtable` using SQLyog GUI and next drop it on source if required

3)  RENAME `newtable` on target if required

This will reduce network traffic to only consider only the rows you want to transfer. And you will avoid exporting to a file as the 'reduction' is kept inside the source server (does not involve file system or network).

Comment: I only had read-only access on the source database so this wasn't an option, unfortunately.  Thanks anyway.